# How to make url_for return slashed parameters rather than (? & based parameters)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails 2.3.5:

Routes:

```
map.connect ':controller/:action/:sort_key/:sort_order'
```

options:

```
{"controller"=>"sections", "action"=>"list", "params"=>{"sort_key"=>"sect_code", "sort_order"=>"asc"}}
```

`url_for(options)` will give me:

```
/sections/list/sect_code/asc
```

In Rail 4.2,

Routes:

```
  get ':controller/:action/:sort_key/:sort_order'
```

`url_for(options)` (same options) will give me,

```
/sections/list?sort_key=sect_code&sort_order=asc
```

Is this difference intended? Is it possible to make the behaviour same?

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect that route isn't being used to generate that URL, and that something else in your routes file is matching first.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is intended. When you add a parameter to url_for options that isn't a controller, an action or an expected property (eg. trailing_slash: true) then the url_for helper will generate a string with the parameters appended in a 'get' fashion. I don't know of any inbuilt way to modify the string output to become slashes instead of get parameters, but since a html encoded string is produced, you could probably get away with using a gsub and regex on the resulting string.

I would create a helper method that modifies the result of the url_for method like the following:

```
def url_for_with_slashes(options=nil)
    url_for(options).gsub(/(\?|&)[a-zA-Z0-9_]+=/, "/")
end
```

Its not completely fool proof, but you can always update the regex if you find that something slips the net.

EDIT: On reflection, you could just assign a name to your route in the routes.rb file

```
get ':controller/:action/:sort_key/:sort_order', as: 'sort'
```

...and then generate this url with slashes using sort_path(sort_key, sort_order)